# How to extract tables from partly unstructured txt files in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, text-extraction, readr

I have a list of URLs for txt files. The txt files are structured such that some parts are plain text, and some parts are tables. I want to extract the tables and export them to a data frame. Below is an example of a URL:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000275/0001140361-13-007449.txt

The txt files are structured such that the tables begin with `<TABLE>` and end with `</TABLE>`. I would like to combine all the tables. I have tried using read.delim but I don't know how to use it for just the tables. Below is an example of the expected output. I would appreciate any guidance on how to proceed with my project.

```
Example of current df:
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                                   URL                                    |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000097/0000919574-13-001835.txt |
|  2 | https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000275/0001140361-13-007449.txt |
|  3 | https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000742/0000898432-13-000218.txt |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Example of txt file from url:

text text text
text text text
text text text

<TABLE>
+---------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   NAME OF ISSUER    | TITLE OF CLASS |   CUSIP   | VALUE (x1000 | SHRS OR PRN AMT | SH/PRN | PUT/CALL | INVESTMENT DISCRETION | OTHER MNGRS | VOTING AUTHORITY |
+---------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
| ABBVIE INC          | COM            | 00287Y109 |        1,547 |          45,300 | SHS    |          | Shared-Defined        | 1/2/3       |           45,300 |
| ABERCROMBIE & FITCH | CL A           | 002896207 |        4,797 |         100,000 | SHS    |          | Shared-Defined        | 1/2/3       |          100,000 |
+---------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
</TABLE>

<TABLE>
+---------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
|   NAME OF ISSUER    | TITLE OF CLASS |   CUSIP   | VALUE (x1000 | SHRS OR PRN AMT | SH/PRN | PUT/CALL | INVESTMENT DISCRETION | OTHER MNGRS | VOTING AUTHORITY |
+---------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
| ABBVIE INC          | COM            | 00287Y109 |        1,547 |          45,300 | SHS    |          | Shared-Defined        | 1/2/3       |           45,300 |
| ABERCROMBIE & FITCH | CL A           | 002896207 |        4,797 |         100,000 | SHS    |          | Shared-Defined        | 1/2/3       |          100,000 |
+---------------------+----------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
</TABLE>



Expected output:
+----+----------------+----------------+-------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
| ID | NAME OF ISSUER | TITLE OF CLASS | CUSIP | VALUE (x1000 | SHRS OR PRN AMT | SH/PRN | PUT/CALL | INVESTMENT DISCRETION | OTHER MNGRS | VOTING AUTHORITY |
+----+----------------+----------------+-------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
|  1 | x              | x              | x     | x            | x               | x      | x        | x                     | x           | x                |
|  1 | x              | x              | x     | x            | x               | x      | x        | x                     | x           | x                |
|  1 | x              | x              | x     | x            | x               | x      | x        | x                     | x           | x                |
|  2 | x              | x              | x     | x            | x               | x      | x        | x                     | x           | x                |
|  2 | x              | x              | x     | x            | x               | x      | x        | x                     | x           | x                |
|  2 | x              | x              | x     | x            | x               | x      | x        | x                     | x           | x                |
+----+----------------+----------------+-------+--------------+-----------------+--------+----------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Well, the first step would be to locate the text chunks betwen `<TABLE>` and `</TABLE>`.  How did you get on with that?  Then you'd need to parse the cell definitions in each chunk.  Give us something to work with!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck at that part, too. I have looked online and tried several approaches, including `fread`, `read.pattern`, and `Readlines` but I'm unable to make them work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rough solution.

```
# Read the text files from the web
fileContents <- readr::read_file("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000275/0001140361-13-007449.txt")
# Extract the tables.  The regex isn't quite right, as it includes the starting <TABLE>
# and ending </TABLE> tags, but more complicated regexes failed.  Regex isn't my
# strong point, and I can handle the extra work
tables <- stringr::str_extract_all(
            fileContents, 
            stringr::regex("(?s)<TABLE>(.*?)</TABLE>", 
              multiline=TRUE, 
              dotall=TRUE
            )
          )

# Function to process a single tibble
toTibble <- function(y) {
  lines <- str_split_fixed(y, "\n", n=Inf)
  colStarts <- c()
  colEnds <- c()
  # Scroll through to final table header
  for (i in 1:(length(lines)-1)) { # Final line is '</TABLE>' because of initial regex
    # Could probably to this with regexes, but my head is hurting
    if (any(!is.na(stringr::str_locate(lines[i], "<\\w>")))) {
      # Define column widths based on locations of type markers.  THIS IS AN ASSUMPTION
      colStarts <- stringr::str_locate_all(lines[i], "<\\w>")[[1]][,"start"]
      for (i in 1:(length(colStarts)-1)) colEnds[i] <- colStarts[i+1] -1
      colEnds[length(colStarts)] <- stringr::str_length(lines[i])
      lines <- lines[(i+1):(length(lines)-1)]
      data <- dplyr::bind_rows(
                lapply(
                  lines,                   # For each data line  
                  function(line) 
                    tibble::enframe(       # Split in to columns and convert to a tibble of name/value pairs
                      stringr::str_trim(
                        stringr::str_sub(
                          line, 
                          colStarts, 
                          colEnds
                        )
                      )
                    ) %>%                  # Convert from name/value pairs to columns
                    tidyr::pivot_wider(
                      values_from="value", 
                      names_from="name", 
                      names_prefix="Column"
                    )
                  )
                )
      # Finished
      return(data)
    }
  }
}
```

To process a single file:

```
firstTable <- toTibble(tables[[1]][[1]])
firstTable
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 59 x 12
   Column1  Column2       Column3   Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10 Column11 Column12
   <chr>    <chr>         <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
 1 AAR CORP COM           000361105 190     10158   SH      ""      DEFINED "2"     10158    0        0       
 2 AAR CORP COM           000361105 15      803     SH      ""      DEFINED "3"     0        0        803     
 3 AAR CORP COM           000361105 37      2000    SH      ""      DEFINED "5"     2000     0        0       
 4 AAR CORP COM           000361105 78      4200    SH      ""      DEFINED ""      4200     0        0       
 5 ABB LTD  SPONSORED ADR 000375204 2164    104112  SH      ""      DEFINED "3"     257      0        103855  
 6 ABB LTD  SPONSORED ADR 000375204 10774   518215  SH      ""      DEFINED "5"     518215   0        0       
 7 ABB LTD  SPONSORED ADR 000375204 64      3100    SH      ""      DEFINED "7"     0        3100     0       
 8 ABB LTD  SPONSORED ADR 000375204 1044    50200   SH      ""      DEFINED "8"     50200    0        0       
 9 ABB LTD  SPONSORED ADR 000375204 9       410     SH      ""      DEFINED "9"     410      0        0       
10 ABB LTD  SPONSORED ADR 000375204 103     4958    SH      ""      DEFINED "15"    4958     0        0       
# … with 49 more rows
```

On my system

```
system.time({firstTable <- toTibble(tables[[1]][[1]])})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.843   0.004   0.849
```

So under a second to process a table.

```
length(tables[[1]])
[1] 299
```

Just under 300 tables in the file, so binding all the tables into a single tibble

```
alldata <- bind_rows(lapply(tables[[1]], function(t) toTibble(t)))
```

Should take about five minutes to extract the tables, plus a little more to bind them all together.  [This code not tested or timed.]

Once you're at this stage, you can play around with column types and names to get exactly what you want.  That should be straightforward.